# ShareLock and ExclusiveLock with postgres database

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, auto-increment, delayed-job

I was checking the lock in logs of one application which is running in heroku and its shows so many lock from delayed_jobs and increment_counter, also these time i got so many timeouts

```
sql_error_code = 00000 LOG: process 129728 still waiting for ShareLock on 
transaction 1296511670 after 1000.149 ms

2017-06-02T16:24:58+00:00 app 
postgres.129728 - - [TEST] [7-2] sql_error_code = 00000 DETAIL: Process
holding the lock: 129457. Wait queue: 129728.

02 Jun 2017 20:24:58.338198 <134>1 2017-06-02T16:24:58+00:00 app
postgres.129728 - - [TEST] [7-3] sql_error_code = 00000 CONTEXT: while 
locking tuple (75,2) in relation "delayed_jobs"

LOG: process 129429 acquired ExclusiveLock on tuple (878044,83) of relation
16953 of database 16385 after 3220.356 ms

02 Jun 2017 20:24:58.338591 <134>1 2017-06-02T16:24:58+00:00 app 
postgres.129728 - - [TEST] [7-4] sql_error_code = 00000 STATEMENT: UPDATE 
"delayed_jobs" SET locked_at = '2017-06-02 16:24:57.033870', locked_by = 
'host:a96aff72dae123123e pid:4' WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM 
"delayed_jobs" WHERE ((run_at <= '2017-06-02 16:24:57.032776' AND (locked_at 
IS NULL OR locked_at < '2017-06-02 12:24:57.032817') OR locked_by = 
'host:a96aff72dae123123e pid:4') AND failed_at IS NULL) 
ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE) RETURNING *

 sql_error_code = 00000 DETAIL: Process holding the lock: 129495. Wait queue: 
 3276.

 02 Jun 2017 20:25:09.279197 <134>1 2017-06-02T16:25:08+00:00 app  
 postgres.3276     
 - - [TEST] [7-3] sql_error_code = 00000 CONTEXT: while updating tuple 
 (878034,120) in relation "messages"


 02 Jun 2017 20:25:09.279248 <134>1 2017-06-02T16:25:08+00:00 app 
 postgres.3276
 - - [TEST] [7-4] sql_error_code = 00000 
 STATEMENT: UPDATE "messages" SET 
 "item_no" = COALESCE("item_no", 0) + 1 WHERE "messages"."id" = 
 48290879
```

I think this is not a normal lock, is there any way to fix these kind of lock?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what you consider a "normal" kind of lock to be.  This is the normal kind of lock you get when multiple transactions try to update (or to `select for update`) on the same tuple at the same time.

But why are the transactions that are taking these locks holding on to them for at least a second?  Are the transactions inherently slow, or are they getting distracted?

Comment: Thanks @jjanes, will this increment_counter method will have any issues? because in one place i can see that it took so much time to update, because in my app this  increment happens so many times

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what the increment_counter method is.  Your description and the snippets of the log file don't really explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: increment_counter function will automatically increment by 1

Comment: Hi @jjanes, any idea on how to solve this "normal kind of lock you get when multiple transactions try to update the same tuple at the same time"? In my case, we are running triggers in table 1 to update a "reporting" table 2 with the tuples so, if we update more than one record in table 1 for the same tuple in table 2, we get the lock error. Thank you so much for your attention and participation.

Comment: @leompeters The lock is only held for the duration of the transaction.  Make every step from when the lock is taken until the transaction commits as fast as possible, or reorder slow steps so they happen before the lock is taken where possible. Without knowing what those steps are, it is hard to offer concrete advice.  Or maybe rethink the design of your reporting table system.  It will inherently limit concurrency.